# How to store the output of a command into a variable in TCSH?

Tags: tcsh

in bash this clearly works

```
$ now=$(date "+%F")
$ echo $now
2022-07-20
```

but in tcsh:

```
>> now=$(date "+%F")
Illegal variable name.
```

Is there a way to store such a thing into a var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csh doesn't support `$()` for command execution, only backticks. And you need to use `set` to assign variables.

```
% set now = `date "+%F"`
% echo $now
2022-07-20
```

Comment: Somehow ``` grave accent didn’t work for me. Will try again.

Comment: Maybe you didn't use `set` @0x90? It's a common error when people are using (t)csh.